# Conditional Statements in SQL query to check multiple values (list) passed as parameter

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4, case, prepared-statement

**Requirement:**

1. When a **Product ID** or multiple **Product IDs** is/are passed, all the information of the Product (Product Name, Price, Quantities Available, Description, etc) should be fetched for the passed Product ID/Product IDs.
2. When **Product ID** is not passed (null), then Product Information of all the available **Product IDs** should be fetched.

In my application, Product_Id is a `List<string>`. I'm passing this list to my SQL Select query as a parameter. If this list is null I have to select all the Product IDs from Product table. If its not null, then I have to fetch only those Product IDs that are in the list.

The query I'm trying to write for the above requirement is given below.

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE PRODUCT_ID IN (?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE @param IS NULL OR PRODUCT_ID IN (@param)
```

?